# Can we Create CSS Selector rule with JQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

we can create style or any other tag with

```
var st = document.createElement("style");
```

and even append the same to body

```
body.append(st);
```

and it will create

```
<body><style></style></body>
```

I wanna know can we put style in style tag with javascript as well not simple rules, I know there is $("selector").css() function is there which can apply css rules to selector but i want a bit more powerful rule and I want to add in style tag i just created,

something like this:

```
<style>
    div.bar {
        text-align: center;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

st.innerHtml or st.innerText are not letting me set these values.

> **Note: This was asked me to do in Browser Console only.**

Comment: why not add class with specified style?

Comment: @guradio usually i do the same but it was asked me in an interview to do so. and interviewer insisted to do that way only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use jquery .text method like

```
const cssCode = `div.bar {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}`
$('style-tag-selector').text(cssCode)
```

but in my opinion, whetever your goal is - this solution is not ok. You shouldn't mess with CSS via JavaScript.

Best approach is to have styles in separately loaded .css file and then you can toggle classes to elements with javascript.

Comment: Actually It was asked to me in a Interview, I usually dont follow this approach, Thanks your answer worked

Answer (score 2):

You can add your css directly within the style tag and append them to the head of your page:

```
$( "head" ).append( "<style>div.bar {text-align: center; color: red}</style>" );
```

You can append multiple style tags with css in the head beneath each other, in this way you can override previous syles, but it is not best practice.

I prefer having your styles in separate files and to manage wether or not the files will be included in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's an interface for this. For example, add a style element and add a rule to it (this will result in anything with the class `should-be-red` to be red.

```
var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
var sheet = styleElement.sheet;
sheet.insertRule('.should-be-red { color: red; }', 0);
```

You can iterate over the rules and insert/delete rules and exciting things like that.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStylesheet

jsbin: https://jsbin.com/jodiro/1/edit?html,js,output